# Copy Data from 1 Excel into another Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am very new in the programming space and tried a lot of things to solve my problem.

It feels like I exactly knew what I have to do, but I can not communicate it in Python.

I have two Excel sheets: wb 1 and wb2.

`wb1` is a self updating sheet from some downloaded CSV data with one table, and extending number of rows on and fix number of columns.

I want to insert the date from `wb1` (column A-J) and the max. number of rows into `wb2` (sheet 3) sheet 3 is a huge table with a lot of data but just the specific part out of wb1 (same positioning as in the wb1 file) needs to be updated.

So I basically want to copy a part out of an workbook and insert int into a specific position into another workbook.

The data in workbook2 is formatted as table so I guess I haive to format the date in workbook1 as table as well before I can copy it. I tried it so far with openpyxl what seems to work great but I can't specify the location in `wb2`.

I knew this is a problem what can be solved within seconds but I am really in a dead end right now.

```
Workbook1 = "download.xlsx"
Workbook2 = "Git.xlsx"

wb1  = xl.load_workbook(filename = Workbook1)
ws1  = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename = Workbook2)
ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name("Table3")
?


wb2.save(path2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've to read all the data from the first sheet which `download.xlsx`, then appened the output value into a list of tuples, after that write the values using the same package `openpyxl` into the second file `Git.xlsx`.

I will not be able to write the whole code because my phone battery is running off. So, i will try to share with you an important links you can follow:-

[Reading using openpyxl](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/)

[Writing using openpyxl](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-writing-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/?ref=rp)

[Lists in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/#:%7E:text=Python%20Lists%201%20Creating%20a%20List.%20Lists%20in,in%20a%20list.The%20index%20...%20More%20items...%20)

[Python List of tuples](https://dzone.com/articles/python-lists-of-tuples)

Comment: if this article helps you, please mark it as "Right Answer"